# DateTime Validation in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my model, I have the following -

```
    [DisplayName("Membership Start")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime MembershipStart { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Membership End")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime MembershipEnd { get; set; }
```

I am entering in the date in my textbox in UK format (DD:MM:YYYY), but the validation will not pass. It says -

> •The value '‎21‎/‎08‎/‎2015' is not valid for Membership Start.

Any ideas what is causing this?

In my Web.Config file, I also have

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

Further investigation is showing the selected date isn't actually getting through to the controller. I am using glDatePicker

http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#examples

My HTML code is as follows -

```
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MembershipStart)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MembershipStart, new { @class = "form-control" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MembershipStart)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MembershipEnd)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MembershipEnd, new { @class = "form-control" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MembershipEnd)
                        </div>
                    </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/glDatePicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#MembershipStart').glDatePicker(
            {
                showAlways: false,
                selectableYears: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048, 2049, 2050, 2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066, 2067, 2068, 2069],
                selectableMonths: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
            }
            );
        $('#MembershipEnd').glDatePicker(
            {
                showAlways: false,
                selectableYears: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030, 2031, 2032, 2033, 2034, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2038, 2039, 2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048, 2049, 2050, 2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 2057, 2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066, 2067, 2068, 2069],
                selectableMonths: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
            }
            );
    });

</script>
```

Comment: pls give us less information that we never can help you.

Comment: What more information is needed? I have the model, the error message and what I have tried.

Comment: @dynamicuser have you got Fiddler installed so you can inspect what is being sent over http (between your browser and the server)?

Comment: @Will It is showing the value property of the text box is not being set with the date